# Why the need to use "à laquelle" in one part and then "à qui" in another?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

> Grâce a toi, je suis avec une femme **à laquelle** je me dévoue entièrement, **à qui** j'ai donné mon cœur.

I’m not sure why you can’t repeat the use of "à laquelle" in this sentence.

> Grâce a toi, je suis avec une femme **à laquelle** je me dévoue entièrement, **à laquelle** j'ai donné mon cœur.

Comment: Dans ta phrase tu peux très bien dire « à laquelle j'ai donné un cœur » et « à qui je me dévoue ». Par contre si l'antécédent était une chose on emploierait uniquement « à laquelle ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your context, you could use both, as pointed by Laure in comments.

However, I think this is simply a basic rule of writing here, not to write two same formulations in the same sentence.

So

> Grâce a toi, je suis avec une femme **à laquelle** je me dévoue entièrement, **à qui** j'ai donné mon cœur.
>
> Grâce a toi, je suis avec une femme **à qui** je me dévoue entièrement, **à laquelle** j'ai donné mon cœur.

are absolutely correct. However, the formulation "*à qui*" **only refers to a person**; this is like saying *to whom* in English. Which means

> la fleur à qui je pensais

is **incorrect**. You have to say

> la fleur à laquelle je pensais

Comment: Not only a person, e.g. *le chat à qui j'ai donné un bol de lait*.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, ***laquelle*** and ***qui*** might be used in either or both case in your sentence.

> Grâce à toi, je suis avec une femme **à qui** je me dévoue entièrement, **à laquelle** j'ai donné mon cœur.

However, one slight difference is ***laquelle*** usually means "**one from a known set**" while ***qui*** has not this restriction and is then open.

See the difference between:

> – **À qui** vas-tu offrir ces fleurs ? → The question is open, anyone might receive them, including more than one person or just nobody.
>
> – **À laquelle** vas-tu offrir ces fleurs ? → It is assumed by both parties that a list of potential receivers is known and one and only one of them will get the flowers.

This explains why the first sentence is the one that would probably be the most natural. Moreover, French tend to avoid repetition so your second suggestion would be also less likely to be used.

When following a preposition like ***à, pour, vers, de, avec, sans, etc.***, the pronoun ***qui*** is restricted to living beings, whatever their gender or number.

On the other hand, ***laquelle*** refer to singular and feminine word which can be a living being (***qui***), a thing (***quoi***) or a location (***où***).

> ‑ **À qui** est cette voiture ? (**Whose** car is this ?)
>
> ‑ **À laquelle** (d'entre vous) est cette voiture ? (if said in front of a group composed of men and women, the question is not directed to the men)
>
> ---
>
> ‑ **À quoi** j'ai droit ? (**What** am I entitled to ?)
>
> ‑ **À laquelle/Auquel** ai-je droit ? (**Which one of these** am I entitled to ?)

---

> ‑ **Où** tu descends ? ( **Where** will you get off ?)
>
> ‑ **À laquelle** tu descends ? (**At which one** (of the stops/stations) will you get off ?)

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour, 
I think first part concern an common object (or concept) : "avec une femme".
Second part is more "human" and concern a specific person.

Illustration :
"Elisabeth à qui j'ai donné mon coeur, est une femme à laquelle je ne peux échapper !"

But sometime you can also make an objet more like a person : "Cette femme à qui j'ai confié mon enfant ..."